# Excel office 2010 Data from one cell displayed based on data in a third cell

Tags: worksheet-function

I use the min function to get the lowest value from a column.  What I would also like is an associated number string from the next column to put in the next display column.  For example:
I have data in column C, rows 10 thru 224, in column D, I a numeric string.  In column H7 I use the min function to display the lowest value in column C, say 45 is located at cell C154; and 20682487 is located in D154.  45 appears in H7 just fine, but I want to pull the data from D154 into I7 also.  thanks ----

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX(D10:D224,MATCH(MIN(C10:C224),C10:C224,0))
```